# Put the variables that returned false in their own array

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse

My code prints "zach" into a separate array. My "isNonStopWord" looks to see if any of the words in skoal appear in "zach". If they do it returns false next to these words that appear in both and true next to every word in "zach" that is not in "skoal" all I am trying to do now is to put all of the words that returned false into their own array and I cannot figure out how to do it. If you have an idea please let me know.

```
  package zk;

 import java.util.Arrays;
 public class Class {

 public boolean isNonStopWord(String x, String[] y) {

    if (Arrays.asList(y).contains(x)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Class cs = new Class();

    String zach = ("Amazon offered up more answers Thursday about what"
            + " caused a bunch of websites to fail two days ago. According "
            + "to a postmortem by the company's cloud services business, "
            + "around 9:37 a.m. PT Tuesday an Amazon worker incorrectly"
            + " punched in a command while trying to debug an issue. "
            + "That command shut down a large set of servers at Amazon Web "
            + "Services' Northern Virginia site, causing a domino effect of"
            + " problems. Other services that relied on those S3 cloud"
            + " storage servers were disrupted. Also, removing so much "
            + "server capacity required a full system restart, which then "
            + "took longer than expected, AWS said. The sites affected "
            + "included Quora, Imgur, IFTTT, Giphy and Slack. Amazon was "
            + "able to fix the issue by about 2 p.m. PT.");

    String [] skoal = {"THE", "BE", "TO", "OF", "AND", "A", "IN",
            "THAT", "I", "IT", "ON", "IN", "BUT", "IS", "WITH"};



    zach = zach.replace(",","");
    zach = zach.replace(".","");
    zach = zach.toUpperCase();
    String [] strings = zach.split(" ");

int july = 0;



    for (String s1: strings)
    {
        boolean answer = cs.isNonStopWord(s1,skoal);
        System.out.println((s1) + "  " + (answer));
        if(answer==false){
            july++;
    }
  }


    System.out.println("There are " + july +" " + "non-stop words");
    zach = "...";           

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a List, because you can dynamically add Elements.

```
ArrayList<String> fooList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s1: strings)
    {
        boolean answer = cs.isNonStopWord(s1,skoal);
        System.out.println((s1) + "  " + (answer));
        if(answer==false){
            july++;
fooList.add(s1);

    }
```

Otherwise I'd take the count of `july`
And instanciate an Array with this size.

```
String[] foo = new String[july]
```

Then you need another for each Loop to fill the Array:(Outside of the other one)

```
int count=0; For ( x: xx) ... if(answer==false){
foo[count] = x;
        count++; }
```

Using a List might be way cleaner and if you need an Array, you can convert the list to one.

```
String [] fooArray = fooList.toArray(new String[july]);
```

Comment: I'm afraid you might have wasted your time.  Read [Elliott Frisch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152066#comment73380873\_43152066) --- there's a good chance that this question (and this user) are going to get deleted soon.  (I, for one, have flagged it / them for moderator attention.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, I sounds like you are asking for a way to print the false and true words separately.

First thing I did is change your last `if` statement to an `if else`, and place the `System.out.println((s1) + "  " + (answer));` statement within the `else` part of `the if else`. Then I put a statement that would add `s1` to the `ArrayList` of false words and placed that statement within the `if` part of the `if else`.

Finally, i used a `for` loop to cycle through the false word and print them followed by "false". Take a look:

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //Create an ArrayList for the false words

        for (String s1: strings)
        {
            boolean answer = cs.isNonStopWord(s1,skoal);
            if(answer==false){
                july++;
                list.add(s1); //If the word is false, add it to the list
        }else{
            System.out.println((s1) + "  " + (answer)); //If the word is true, print it
        }
      }

        String[] falses = new String[list.size()]; //
        falses = list.toArray(falses);             // Convert the ArrayList to a regular array for processing 

        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){         //
            System.out.println(falses[i] + " false"); // Cycle through the array of false words and print them followed by "false"
        }                                             //

        System.out.println("There are " + july +" " + "non-stop words");
        zach = "...";           
        }
```

Comment: Same thing I said to the other answer's author:  There's a good chance that this question (and this user) are going to get deleted soon.  (See also: [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)).